Excluding records between dates AND with an associating value
I am trying return a dataset that fall between a 30 day window and belong to another set of values.
Here is how the table looks:
|   EMAIL   |    LIST    |   CREATED_DATE   |
---------------------------------------------
|  email1       prop1        2024-06-12     |
|  email2       prop2        2024-06-05     |
|  email3       prop1        2024-05-11     |
|  email4       prop3        2024-06-30     |
---------------------------------------------

So I want to exclude anything on LIST prop1, prop2, and prop3 that was created during June.
The return records should look like this:
|   EMAIL   |    LIST    |   CREATED_DATE   |
---------------------------------------------
|  email3       prop1        2024-05-11     |
---------------------------------------------

Although email3 is on prop1, it falls outside of the date criteria.
Here is the query I have now:
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (`created_date` NOT BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30' 
AND `LIST` NOT IN ('prop1','prop2','prop3'))

But that query removes everything that is in prop1, prop2, and prop3.
I still need to return the prop1 records that falls outside of the date range.
How can I fix this?

Did you forget WHERE?

@PM77-1 - Typo.  I updated the question.

Another typo: You have prop2 twice in the query.

I have added one more row to your example:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/29RMhJmsJ9CSkaXJULX1ie/1

Combine the two conditions, then negate it to make it an exclusion.
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE NOT (
    created_date BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30' 
    AND list IN ('prop1','prop2','prop3')
)

And if you then apply deMorgan's Laws to this, you get the equivalent:
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE created_date NOT BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30' 
    OR list NOT IN ('prop1','prop2','prop3')

which is the same as your query, except AND is replaced with OR.

Adding the OR clause is what did it for me.  Thank you, sir.
